# List Insert STL

Tags: c++, list, stl, insert

I don't understand why my code doesn't insert to the list.

But if I change the line where I use the insert by doing a push_back the element is inserted to the list. Thank you

But I have to have it sorted. The operator < is well implemented:

```
void  Movies::afegirPeliculaDirector(string director,string title,int year){
      list<actorDirectorMovie> llista;
      actorDirectorMovie dir(title,year);
      int total=_mapDirectors.count(director);
      if (total>0){
             map<string,list<actorDirectorMovie> >::iterator                   
             it=_mapDirectors.find(director);
             llista=(*it).second;
             list<actorDirectorMovie>::iterator itList=(*it).second.begin();
             while(itList!=(*it).second.end() and (*itList) < dir){
                itList++;
             }
             if (itList==(*it).second.end()) llista.push_back(dir);
             else {
                 cout << llista.size() << endl;
                 llista.insert(itList,dir);//->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IT DOESN'T INSERT, WHY?
                 cout << llista.size() << endl;
             }
             it->second=llista;
     }
     else {
       llista.push_back(dir);
      _mapDirectors.insert(make_pair(director,llista));
  }
  directorMovies(director);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `itList` iterator refers to a different container. `itList` points to a member of `_mapDirectors[director].second` but you're trying to use it as an insertion point into `llista`.

I think the problem is that you wanted `llista` to be a reference to the mapped list, but instead you're making a copy of it.

Try the following code (I haven't tested it but it should give you the idea). Note that it takes a *reference* to the mapped list. There's also no need to test for an empty map, or do an explicit `find` for the director - you can simply reference `_mapDirectors[director].second` and the empty list will be created automatically if it's not already in the map.

```
void  Movies::afegirPeliculaDirector(string director,string title,int year)
{
    // get a reference to the director's list
    list<actorDirectorMovie>& llista = _mapDirectors[director];
    actorDirectorMovie dir(title,year);

    list<actorDirectorMovie>::iterator itList=llista.begin();
     while(itList!=llista.end() and (*itList) < dir){
        itList++;
     }
     if (itList==llista.end()) llista.push_back(dir);
     else {
         cout << llista.size() << endl;
         llista.insert(itList,dir);
         cout << llista.size() << endl;
     }
}
```

You could also consider changing from using a `list` to store each director's movies to a `set`, as this has the property of being sorted automatically for you. The whole function would be reduced to `_mapDirectors[director].insert(dir)` in that case.